How to properly increment variable in LazyColumn
I want make simple 30 days app with hardcoded data, but I have variable that stands for current day, I want to increment it, but when I do it, it's doing it not quite right.
@Composable
fun _30DaysApp() {
    var curDay by remember { mutableStateOf(1) }
    Scaffold(topBar = {
    }) { it ->
        LazyColumn(contentPadding = it) {
            items(tasks) {
                CardTask(task = it, day = curDay)
                curDay++

            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CardTask(task: Task, day: Int, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    var expand by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Card(shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)) {
        Column(
            modifier = modifier
                .padding(12.dp)
        ) {
            Row {
                Text(text = stringResource(R.string.day, day))
                Spacer(modifier = modifier.weight(1f))
                ExpandButton(expanded = expand, onClick = { expand = !expand })
            }
            Text(text = stringResource(task.articleRes))
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(8.dp))
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(task.imageRes), contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
            )
        }
    }
}

Tried to hoist it to function CardTask but it's still not working. Could anyone help me please?

It might help if you include the code that increments curDay

As I see it, you can completely remove that variable. You don't need a state for anything. Instead, build your LazyColumn like this:
LazyColumn(contentPadding = it) {
    itemsIndexed(tasks) { index, task ->
        CardTask(task = task, day = index + 1)
    }
}

The only thing that would merit such a variable would be if you want to change the "+ 1" for some reason during runtime. Then a state variable is needed. But it must not be changed while buildng the LazyColumn.

Thanks a lot. Everything is working now
